# Packetloss from a openVPN-client to a VLAN it's attached to

Tags: networking, server, openvpn, vlan

i am a bit lost with this one und would be gratefull for your help!

**The Setup**
Network consists of HP V1910-24G switches. The whole company running at VLAN-ID 100 within 192.168.2.0. The server which is running openVPN-server on Ubuntu Server is attached to VLAN-ID 30 within 192.168.22.0.

The Server is running: *Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-70-generic x86_64)*

In the future, i wan't to create multiple vlans with VPNs which connect to them. So consider this to be the evaluation setup.

**The Servers Interfaces**
is connected to Port 14 on a switch, which is configured like this:

```
untagged membership: 30
tagged membership: 100
Link Type: Hybrid
PVID: 30
```

The interfaces of the server:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:cc:6a:44:e0:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.22.100/24 brd 192.168.22.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4ecc:6aff:fe44:e0db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::877c:3d1b:90fa:736a/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:0c:12:89:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: VLAN_100@enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:cc:6a:44:e0:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.100/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global VLAN_100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4ecc:6aff:fe44:e0db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**The openVPN config**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ......
cer ......
key ......
dh ......
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.22.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

---

**The Problem** 
I can't ping any device in the 192.168.2.0 net besides the gateway/router (192.168.2.1), over the vpn-connection. 99% of the packets get lost. Here i have a tcpdump, showing a ping-packet, that succeded back to the pinging device.

```
13:52:33.558835  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.2.20: ICMP echo request, id 5501, seq 51, length 64
13:52:33.558862 Out 4c:cc:6a:44:e0:db ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.2.20: ICMP echo request, id 5501, seq 51, length 64
13:52:33.558866 Out 4c:cc:6a:44:e0:db ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 104: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.2.20: ICMP echo request, id 5501, seq 51, length 64
13:52:33.559398  In 00:1d:aa:b5:ee:e8 ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 104: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 192.168.2.20 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 5501, seq 51, length 64
13:52:33.559398  In 00:1d:aa:b5:ee:e8 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.2.20 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 5501, seq 51, length 64
13:52:33.559427 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.2.20 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 5501, seq 51, length 64
```

Here is a packet which did not reach back to the VPN client.

```
13:52:34.571763  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.2.20: ICMP echo request, id 5501, seq 52, length 64
13:52:34.571790 Out 4c:cc:6a:44:e0:db ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.2.20: ICMP echo request, id 5501, seq 52, length 64
13:52:34.571794 Out 4c:cc:6a:44:e0:db ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 104: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.2.20: ICMP echo request, id 5501, seq 52, length 64
13:52:34.572286  In 00:1d:aa:b5:ee:e8 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.2.20 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 5501, seq 52, length 64
```

Seems like something is wrong with the vlan_tag on the packets.
Pinging from/to the server locally works fine. (192.168.2.100 -> 192.168.2.20 and vice versa)

How can i troubleshot this? Thank you all!

---

**ip route show**

```
default via 192.168.22.1 dev enp2s0 proto static
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.2.0/24 dev VLAN_100 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.100
192.168.22.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.100
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the whole idea is wrong.

With this way a ping packet is directly sent from the OpenVPN server to 192.168.2.20 over VLAN 100. 192.169.2.20 answers to 10.8.0.6, but has to send its answer to the gateway (192.168.2.1), because it doesn't know 10.8.0.6. At this point it probably it get's dropped, because it comes from another mac address as it was sent to.

Because there is a gateway anyway between VLANs, I just added a static rule from 192.168.22.100 to 192.168.2.0 and vice verse from 192.168.2.0 to 10.8.0.0. So now there's a gateway between the server and all VLANs.